# Simple WPF Databinding syntax for 'Path' property

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, syntax, path

Can anyone explain why, when setting a binding, sometimes you do it with quotes around the binding path -

```
<myObject.myProperty>
    <Binding Path="myData" />
<myObject.myProperty/>
```

and sometimes without -

```
<myObject myProperty="{Binding Path=myData}" />
```

?

Microsoft (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059.aspx#xaml_syntax_in_brief) state -

```
"An attribute syntax names the property that is 
 being set in attribute syntax, followed by the 
 assignment operator (=). The value of an attribute 
 is always specified as a string that is contained
 within quotation marks."
```

But here we always specify the Path attribute of the Binding element without quotes. Am I not understanding something about the {} syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a feature of data binding *per se*. The same applies to any markup extension. For example, the quotes/no quotes variation you describe can also be found with the `StaticResource` markup extension as this example shows:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="b" Color="Red" />
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <TextBlock
        Foreground="{StaticResource b}"
        Text="Foo"/>
    <TextBlock
        Text="Foo">
        <TextBlock.Foreground>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="b" />
        </TextBlock.Foreground>
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

It boils down to this: if you're using an XML element to instantiate a markup extension (such as `Binding` or `StaticResource`) and if you set the properties as attributes, the syntax rules of XML require quotes. This is outside of XAML's control - XML syntax requires quotes around all attribute values.

But if you use the markup syntax extension (i.e. {...}), quotes are optional for properties you set inside those braces. That's because the markup extension syntax is not a feature of XML. It's a feature of XAML, and Microsoft therefore has control over the syntax. One goal of markup extensions is to reduce verbosity, and since it was possible for Microsoft to make quotes optional, they did so. (In fact, requiring quotes would have been messy, because you then tend to get into escaping issues - when a markup extension is the value of an attribute it's already encased in quotes, so requiring nested quotes could get messy.)

There's a third syntax, by the way:

```
<myObject.myProperty>
    <Binding>
        <Binding.Path>myData</Binding.Path>
    </Binding>
<myObject.myProperty/>
```

A `Binding` is just an object like anything else in XAML, so you can set its properties using either attributes or property elements. By setting `Path` as a property element, I get to supply its value as the content of that property element. XML syntax rules don't require quotes around the content of an element, so once again I get to omit the quotes.

So it all really comes down to XML's rules for where data needs quotes. It doesn't have much to do with XAML, and isn't at all specific to data binding.

Comment: Concise answer and very understandable. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks - glad you liked it. Any chance you could mark it as an answer?